# How to create a RichTextBox in C# and measure its size?

Tags: silverlight, windows-phone-7

I want to create multiple `RichTextBox` to deal with the `UIElement` 2048px max size restriction on Windows Phone.
I'm aware there's a [scrollable-textblock](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/priozersk/archive/2010/09/08/creating-scrollable-textblock-for-wp7.aspx) solution.

Here's my test code:

```
RichTextBox rtb = new RichTextBox();
rtb.TextWrapping = TextWrapping.Wrap;
rtb.FontSize = (Application.Current.Resources["PhoneFontSizeMedium"] as double?).Value;
rtb.FontFamily = Application.Current.Resources["PhoneFontFamilyNormal"] as FontFamily;
rtb.Width = this.Width;
Run run = new Run();
run.Text = "Hello World.Hello World.Hello World.Hello World.Hello World.";
Paragraph para = new Paragraph();
para.Inlines.Add(run);
rtb.Blocks.Add(para);
double rtbh = rtb.ActualHeight;
BodyPanel.Children.Add(rtb);
```

`BodyPanel` is a `StackPanel`, the application runs fine, however, the `ActualHeight` property always returns 0 in the debug window.

If I define a `RichTextBox` in XAML and set its content in C#, its size properties are all normal.

So how can I create a RichTextBox in pure C# and get its size measurements?

BTW, I cannot find any official documentation on the 2048px restriction.

Comment: Could you solve the problem using this solution?

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11325299/custom-richtextbox-control

Comment: I'm afraid I overlooked that solution. I could use an invisible `RichTextBox` in the XAML to measure its size. But I'm wondering if I could do it in pure C#. I'll have stick with this workaround for the moment. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ActualHeight property returns 0 because the RichTextBox is not rendered in the UI. You are trying to measure an element which is not yet added in the UI, so its height is 0. Once you add it in the UI and it gets rendered, you will get the correct ActualHeight.

You can try this code:

```
            RichTextBox rtb = new RichTextBox();
            rtb.TextWrapping = TextWrapping.Wrap;
            rtb.FontSize = 12;
            rtb.FontFamily = new FontFamily("Arial");
            rtb.Width = this.Width;
            Run run = new Run();
            run.Text = "Hello World.Hello World.Hello World.Hello World.Hello World.";
            Paragraph para = new Paragraph();
            para.Inlines.Add(run);
            rtb.Blocks.Add(para);

            BodyPanel.Children.Add(rtb);
            Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() =>
                {
                    double rtbh = rtb.ActualHeight;
                });
```

Comment: Thanks for explaining the reason. Since [this post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/priozersk/archive/2010/09/08/creating-scrollable-textblock-for-wp7.aspx) repeatedly measures `ActualHeight`, I'm a little concerned about its performance.